# C - wrong result ( strcmp )

Tags: c

This function never return 1, always `strcmp(auxiliar->nick,nuevonick) != 0`

```
int comparar_nick(char *nuevonick){

      struct _usuario *auxiliar;

      auxiliar = primerousuario;
      while (auxiliar!=NULL) {

            if( strcmp(auxiliar->nick,nuevonick) == 0 ) return 1;  

            auxiliar = auxiliar->siguiente;
      }

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are ever going to be equal?

Comment: Probably need trimming.

Comment: is `fgets()` involved somewhere?

Comment: yes i used fgets in a previous function

Comment: Then post all the relevant code.

Comment: Problem is in your strings, not in the code you show now.

Comment: Read the manual page for `fgets`. It says: *If  a  newline  is
       read,  it  is  stored into the buffer.*

Comment: Please read `fgets` man page, about how it retains any `newline` entered.

Comment: check like this `else fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG:'%s', '%s'\n", auxiliar->nick,nuevonick);`

Comment: okay, thx    i swap fgets to gets and now its ok!

Comment: `gets` is obsolete and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `gets` is obsolete. If you are using `fgets` to read an input, it retains any `newline` entered. You can remove that `newline` with this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
...

char instring[100];
int found;
if(fgets(instring, sizeof instring, stdin) != NULL) {
    instring [ strcspn(instring, "\r\n") ] = 0;         // remove trailing newline etc
    found = comparar_nick(instring);
}
```